# Set filter before_action for ActiveAdmin controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to add **before_action** filter to ActiveAdmin controller.

Could I do something like this:

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

private

def set_product
  @product = Product.find_by_name(params[:name])
end
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get any errors? Did it work as expected? If yes, then yes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access the controller from within the `controller do ... end` DSL:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  controller do
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find_by_name(params[:name])
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: For newer versions of activeadmin, `before_filter` should be within the controller block.

Comment: @OscarBarrett No, it works for me for the latest version of Active Admin (at the moment of writing this).

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in the config: `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  def do_something_awesome
  end

  config.before_action :do_something_awesome      
end
```